# How to resolve dependency issues when installing multimaster-fkie on Ubuntu ARM?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to install multimaster-fkie with the command

**sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-multimaster-fkie**

I get the following error message

**--------@---------:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-multimaster-fkie
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libqt4-opengl-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**

when I try to run, as suggested, **sudo apt-get -f install** I get the following error message.

**trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h', which is also in package libraspberrypi-dev 1.20150502.d280099-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libegl1-mesa-dev_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4_armhf.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa-dev_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

So my question is: Do anyone know if it is possible to resolve the dependency issues for libegl1-mesa-dev and libgles2-mesa-dev such that the installation is successful?

Im running a ubuntu 14.04 ARM on a Raspberry PI 2. The image is taken from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218263/how-to-resolve-dependency-issues-when-installing-multimaster-fkie-on-ubuntu-arm?/) by [naits3](https://answers.ros.org/users/24050/naits3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-09-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on 2016-02-22**:
Did you ever solve this, I receive the same error on my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running Ubuntu 14.04?

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-03-24**:
Same for me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the above link is broken, Ill repeat (and facilitate) the solution from http://forums.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=100553&start=200 here. Also just ran into the problem ..

Basically its

```
sudo apt-get download libegl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev 
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl1-mesa-dev_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa-dev_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Maybe you need to replace the versions in the middle commands with something different .. tab-autocomplete is your friend ;)

---

Originally posted by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) with karma: 95 on 2017-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2019-06-03**:
Alternatively, you can specify dpkg to force overwrite through apt-get directly, e.g: `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libegl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev`